# ByteConversionUtil ByteBuffer java compile error

Tags: java, compilation, bytebuffer

completed my code but after numerous attempts of debugging i am still unable to compile it successfully. the problem lies here but i can't seem to find the correct method to correct it.

```
private static class ByteConversionUtil {
    private static ByteBuffer longBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    private static ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer
            .allocate(Integer.BYTES);

    private static byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
        longBuffer.putLong(0, value);
        return longBuffer.array();
    }

    private static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] array) {
        intBuffer.put(array, 0, array.length);
        intBuffer.flip();
        return intBuffer.getInt();
    }
```

Comment: How did you debug a non-compiling code?

Comment: Show your imports, please.

Comment: @PM77-1 sorry but i don't quite get your comments? and i found that the problem lies in the 'Long.BYTES' and 'Integer.BYTES'. But how should i change it.

Comment: Your class is **static**.  It means it should have an `outer` class to compile.

Comment: @PM77-1 Hmm does this count as an outer class: class FileSender {....}

Comment: Yep. And it should be in `FileSender.java` file. Assuming that you already have `import java.nio.ByteBuffer;` at the very top, it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you probably want to change your code from

```
private static ByteBuffer longBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
private static ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES);
```

to

```
private static ByteBuffer longBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE);
private static ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE);
```

Long.SIZE allocates 64 bytes to the buffer.
Integer.SIZE allocates 32 bytes to the buffer.